# Setting session timeout period with Spring Security 3.0

Tags: java, spring-security, session-timeout

I am using Spring Security 3.0 to authenticate with an LDAP server and I cannot figure out to set my own session timeout period. I believe that the default is 30 minutes but I need to set it to longer than that

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You can either set the session timeout (say 60 minutes) for all sessions in web.xml:

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>60</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

or on a per-session basis using

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60*60);
```

the latter you might want to do in a authorizationSuccessHandler.

```
<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>
```

Comment: session-timeout, that was it! Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks 
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60*60*24);  
This code sets 24 hour session time.

Comment: @sourcedelica this implementation throwing msg stating "Full authentication is required to access this resource"  can we change this message ?

Comment: server.session.timeout= # Session timeout in seconds - for Spring Boot

Comment: `session-config` - should be added into `web.xml` file

Comment: What if I am using spring boot and dont have web.xml?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using **Spring Boot** you can do so by adding the following to the **application.properties** file:

```
server.session.cookie.max-age=<your_value_in_seconds>
```