# Session timeout in Spring Boot app behind Apache

Tags: java, apache, session, tomcat, spring-boot

My app uses Spring Boot and I want the user sessions timeout to be 12h.
I put the server.session.timeout=43200 in my application.properties but the session is still expiring long before the 12 hours.

The app runs in a Tomcat 7 instance behind an Apache server. Do I need to do any extra configuration in the container or server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those properties (`server.*`) only work if SpringBoot is controlling Tomcat (i.e. SpringBoot with an embedded Tomcat deployed as an executable JAR), rather than when deploying it as a WAR into an existing Tomcat instance.

So you'll need to configure the session timeout in one of the 'old' ways:
e.g.

Through Tomcat:
[Default session timeout for Apache Tomcat applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14433070/default-session-timeout-for-apache-tomcat-applications)

Through Spring Security:
[Setting session timeout period with Spring Security 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385175/setting-session-timeout-period-with-spring-security-3-0)

Comment: Thanks! I'll add a request.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(43200); into my AuthenticationSuccessHandler.